# Pull multiple attributes from WMI

Tags: wmi, wmi-query

Is is possible to query multiple WMI sources like you can multiple tables in SQL?

```
@"SELECT Win32_Process.ExecutablePath, Win32_Process.Handle, Win32_Process.Name, Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process.WorkingSetPrivate, Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process.PercentProcessorTime  FROM Win32_Process, Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process
```

This didn't work but hopefully you get the idea. I've searched around and I couldn't even find anyone asking this question. I'm guessing it's not possible but I thought I'd try the experts here before giving up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't. The [`WQL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) language is just a subset of SQL and doesn't supports querys over multiples classes at the same time. Instead you can try the [`ASSOCIATORS OF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384793%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) sentence, but only in some scenarios.